# How to serialize a javascript array object in Newtonsoft JsonConvert in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to serialize javascript array to object using Newtonsoft JsonConvert  in C#. Any help would be appreciated.

*My Javascript array object is:*

```
[
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "Patient_ID": 1,
    "Appointment_ID": 219,
    "ObservationID": "33",
    "arrOption": "{\"ObservationOptionList\":[{\"Observations_Param_Option_ID\":\"77\",\"Extended_Value\":\"\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "Patient_ID": 1,
    "Appointment_ID": 219,
    "ObservationID": "1",
    "arrOption": "{\"ObservationOptionList\":[{\"Observations_Param_Option_ID\":\"1\",\"Extended_Value\":\"Dry\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "Patient_ID": 1,
    "Appointment_ID": 219,
    "ObservationID": "8",
    "arrOption": "{\"ObservationOptionList\":[{\"Observations_Param_Option_ID\":\"25\",\"Extended_Value\":\"\"}]}"
  },
  {
    "ID": 0,
    "Patient_ID": 1,
    "Appointment_ID": 219,
    "ObservationID": "15",
    "arrOption": "{\"ObservationOptionList\":[{\"Observations_Param_Option_ID\":\"40\",\"Extended_Value\":\"\"}]}"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is already serialised. Are you asking how to turn this into a C# object?

Comment: yes ,I want to convert C# object

Comment: What are these items? Patients? Appointments?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean **de**-serialize.

Create a class to hold each Patient.

```
public class Patient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Patient_ID { get; set; }
    public int Appointment_ID { get; set; }
    public string ObservationID { get; set; }
    public string arrOption { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize into a List of Patient.

```
var patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Patient>>(json);
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Create a C# Class

```
class MyClass
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int Patient_ID {get;set;}
    public int Appointment_ID {get;set;}
    public string ObservationID {get;set;}
    public string arrOption {get;set;

}
```

#### Now use deserialize method

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

> If you also want deserialize `arrOption` to a object you need to foreach after deserialize